# Deleting an object using list in swiftUI along with the data

Tags: swiftui, parse-platform, swiftui-list, xcode13

I am trying to figure out the way to delete an item from the `List` in `SwiftUI`. I tried to use the `.onDelete` method, which removes the entry from the array, however I am unsure about how can I see the metadata of the item (i.e. object id or content) and use that condition to delete the item from the backend.

```
        List {
            ForEach(userPostsVM.posts) {
                post in
                FeedViewCell(post: post, isUserPostsView: true)
                    .onAppear{
                        userPostsVM.fetchMoreDataIfNeeded(currentItem: post)
                    }
                
            }.onDelete { indexSet in
                /*this remove the item from the list,
                  however once refreshed the view item
                 is reloaded because it was refetched
                 from the server and was never deleted
                 in the server
                 */
                userPostsVM.posts.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                userPostsVM.deleteUserPost(at: indexSet)
            }
        }
```

**Tried the following method, however the post id never matches to the object deleted from the list rows**

```
func deleteUserPost(at offsets : IndexSet) {
    self.posts.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    offsets.forEach({ index in
        let deletedPostId = self.posts[index].id
        deletePostfromServer(postId: deletedPostId)
    })
}

func deletePostfromServer(postId : String) {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "demoClass")
    query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: postId)
    query.whereKey("user", equalTo: AuthViewModel.shared.currentUser!)
    query.getFirstObjectInBackground { object, _ in
        if let object = object {
            print("DEBUG:  got the object with id \(object.objectId)")
            // above does not match with the object id deleted from the list, hence never runs
        }
    }
}
```

All I am looking for to get is the object detail i.e. `objectId` for the item shown in particular row which was/canbe deleted. `Posts` array is a `Published` property.

I think one solution can be possible by comparing the array state to previous state and get what is not in the current state and finally, use that object to remove from the server backend.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're doing `self.posts[index].id` *after* removing items from `posts`, so the indexes will never match up.

Comment: is there any way to figure out which item is being deleted? I figured, since the item is already deleted a new item takes it's place in the list. so how can i keep track of item which was removed.

Comment: Switch the order of your code and do the forEach before you do the delete